Sending direct inputs to minimized applications? (Games specifically)
I want to make a Python script that can send low level inputs to a Roblox window that is minimized so that I can continue to work on other projects.
There's a million different ways to send low level inputs to games that you have opened and focused, however after looking around for hours I haven't been able to find a single way to do the same but with windows in the background. For example, making the character walk forward in the game, but I can still use my mouse and keyboard to do homework.
Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

What is a "low level input" as opposed to a different kind of input?

@mkrieger1 Another way of saying it is a "direct input". Other types of virtual inputs will get ignored by the game, to make it harder for people to make macros.

You probably can't. If you're simulating keyboard and mouse operations, they can probably only be sent to the active window.

What's your OS? If you have windows, this answer could be helpful, although looking at the comments, it seems it is not working for everybody. As @Barmar said, this is probably impossible. And anyway, the whole purpose of games is so that people play them, not so they can use macros.

@5rod But how are you supposed to cheat if you can't set up a bot to play the game for you in the background?

@Barmar, that's exactly the point. People are not supposed to cheat. But anyway, it probably is possible to run the bot in the background.

@5rod Sorry, was being sarcastic.
